# Counting occurrences of specific events in CUDA kernels

Tags: cuda, monitoring

#### Problem

I am trying to find the best way to count how many times my program ends up in some specific branches of my CUDA kernels. The idea is that some events should nearly never happen, but since the data processed by the GPU is given by a numerical optimization solver, there may be some situations where ill-defined cases become more common. Thus, I want to be able to track/monitor these phenomenons over multiple simulations to make some global statistics later.

#### Possible idea

The most straightforward way to do this may be to use a structure dedicated to monitoring such occurrences. Then, when entering a monitored branch, we increment the associated counter using `atomicAdd`. At the end of the simulation, we copy the counters back to the host and store them for some future statistics processing.

In my case, the cost of using `atomicAdd` should not be that important since I should not be entering those branches that much, but still, I may want to monitor some of the common branches later on, so what would be a better approach then? Since this is just for monitoring, I do not want the overhead to be too important.

I guess I could also have one monitoring structure per block and do a sum at the end, since it should not use much global memory anyway (1 `unsigned int` per monitored branch).

#### Code example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUDA_CHECK_ERROR()  __cuda_check_errors(__FILE__, __LINE__)
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(err) __cuda_safe_call(err, __FILE__, __LINE__)

inline void __cuda_check_errors(const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    cudaError err = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if(err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\n",
               err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

inline void __cuda_safe_call(cudaError err, const char *filename, const int line_number)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("CUDA error %i at %s:%i: %s\n",
               err, filename, line_number, cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(-1);
    }
}

struct Stats
{
    unsigned int even;
};

__global__ void test_kernel(int* A, int* B, Stats* stats)
{
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int res = A[tid] + (int)tid;

    if (res%2 == 0)
        atomicAdd(&(stats->even), 1);

    B[tid] = res;
}

int get_random_int(int min, int max)
{
    return min + (rand() % (int)(max - min + 1));
}

void print_array(int* ar, unsigned int n)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << ar[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void print_stats(Stats* s)
{
    std::cout << "even: " << s->even << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // vector size
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    // device vectors
    int *d_A, *d_B;
    Stats *d_stats;

    // host vectors
    int *h_A, *h_B;
    Stats *h_stats;

    // allocate device memory
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&d_A, N * sizeof(int)));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&d_B, N * sizeof(int)));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(&d_stats, sizeof(Stats)));

    // allocate host memory
    h_A = new int[N];
    h_B = new int[N];
    h_stats = new Stats;

    // initialize host data
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        h_A[i] = get_random_int(0,10);
        h_B[i] = 0;
    }
    memset(h_stats, 0, sizeof(Stats));

    // copy data to the device
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(d_stats, h_stats, sizeof(Stats), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // launch kernel
    dim3 grid_size, block_size;
    grid_size.x = N;
    test_kernel<<<grid_size, block_size>>>(d_A, d_B, d_stats);

    // copy result back to host
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(h_B, d_B, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(h_stats, d_stats, sizeof(Stats), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    print_array(h_B, N);
    print_stats(h_stats);

    // free device memory
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(d_A));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(d_B));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(d_stats));

    // free host memory
    delete [] h_A;
    delete [] h_B;
    delete h_stats;
}
```

#### Hardware/software information

The solution I am looking for should work for `CC >= 2.0` devices and `CUDA >= 5.0`.

Comment: Another option is to use performance monitor events. The event counters can be incremented with `asm("pmevent %0;" :"r"(x));` where `x` is an expression evaluating to in integer between 0 and 15. The counters can then be read through CUPTI.

Comment: As RoBiK just pointed out there is no need for inline assembly any more, just use the `__prof_trigger()` intrinsic function.

Comment: @tera: Profiler counters may not be a good solution in my case since they come with some very strong restrictions (correct me if I'm wrong): only 8 counters available (8 to 15 are reserved apparently), they are incremented per-warp, they are reset before each kernel launch, and kernel launches are synchronous. But this could still be useful in a slightly different context, indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The atomicAdd is is one possibility and i would probably go that route. If you do not use the result of the atomicAdd function call the compiler will emit a reduction operation such as `RED.E.ADD`. Reduction is very fast as long as there are not many conflicts happening  (i actually use it sometimes even if i do not need the operation to be atomic because it can be quicker than loading value from global memory, doing an arithmetic operation and saving back to global memory).
The second option you have is to use a profiler counter and use the profiler to analyze the result. Please see [Profiler Counter Function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#profiler-counter-function) for more details.

Comment: I see. Do you have any example of that reduction operation? Isn't that an optimization that the compiler can do when dealing with global memory "directly"?

Comment: @BenC the way you have written your example is exactly the type of atomicAdd for that the compiler will emit the reduction operation instead of an atomic operation. In `if (res%2 == 0) atomicAdd(&(stats->even), 1);` the result of the atomicAdd call is not placed in any variable so the compiler can emit `red`insead of `atom`. You can check the PTX output to see if the compiler did that.

Comment: I just checked the PTX code and I get `atom.global.add.u32 %r8, [%rd2], 1;`. However, `cuobjdump -sass` does give `RED.E.ADD [R4], R7;`. I guess this optimization is not always visible in intermediary PTX code (and as you said, storing the result leads to `ATOM.E.ADD R0, [R6], R0;`). As for the example I asked, I was referring to your "atomic trick", which is different to what I have here since I do need the operation to be atomic :-)

Comment: @BenC I stand corrected, the PTX really contains `atom.global.add` and  not `red.global.add`, only the SASS contains the `RED` instruction... i am not sure why nvcc does not emit the red PTX instruction, it certainly could. I will correct my answer.

Comment: @BenC about the "reduction trick"... for each threadblock i have an array in the global memory that i only use for output and it is exclusive to that threadblock and written to only by one thread - that means there is no need for atomicity, the theradblock produces output values that need to by accumulated in various output array elements. So instead of doing something like `ouptut[index] += value` i do `atomicAdd(&output[index], value)`.

Comment: Since it appears to be the only way to go and you provided some useful extra information, I decided to accept this answer.